# Can Rails 3 asset pipeline errors be disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Sometimes I'll forget to compile a tiny new image icon or something, and rather than just sending a bad URL to the browser so it can display the little box with a ?, the asset pipeline crashes my entire application. I think this is a little bit overkill. I'd rather have the asset pipeline "fail gracefully" if that's possible. Is there a setting that will disable raising errors in production? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can disable asset pipeline by setting

**config/application.rb**
from

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

to

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

you can also refer to this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html